# How to scaffold additional views beyond Create/Edit/Delete/Details/List in C#'s ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, t4, scaffolding

Currently, when I generate a controller in ASP.NET, I use the "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework" option. I have a custom CodeTemplates folder with my modified t4 files, and these are all generated correctly.

However, I now have an additional Table view I would like to scaffold at the same time as the typical views (Create/Delete/Details/Edit/Index).

Is there a way to include this new t4 file to generate the Table view at the same time as the others? This CodeTemplates folder will be used by other devs in my office, so it would be nice if it all happened at once and I didn't have to include further instructions for how to scaffold additional views individually. Thanks!